# Workbook activate old versus new version of excel

Tags: vba, excel

I had to use very old macro written by former employees
They wrote the code in 2009 and used it on different windows version until windows 7 (and the excel version evolved accordingly).

Now, I try to launch the macro on excel 2016 / windows 10.

I always get an error with the following code:

```
Wb_Template.Sheets("data1").Activate
Call data1_traitement_donnees
```

and the sub:

```
 If Sheets("data1").Cells(i, 1).Value <> Sheets("data1").Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then...
```

I always need to add

`Wb_Template.`

Before `Sheet("data1")`... or I get an error message.
Everything was working fine before.
IS there a modification of this kind of code interpretation?

Comment: It would be useful if you specified the exact versions of Excel that you're talking about, and show the exact error message that you receive. Newer versions of Excel have separate windows for each workbook, so the activation behavior is different. You should always qualify a call to `Sheets` with the workbook reference, otherwise sheets is relative to the active workbook, which you can't rely upon.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2013; I use this way :

```
'Declare your workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

'Declare all your worksheet
Dim sh_test As Worksheet
Set sh_test = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")


If sh_test.Cells(i, 2).Value = "20040155" Then ...
```

You don't need to use activate